# how to pass model and string in mvc5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Thing is model
    var things = [
        { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },
        { id: 2, color: 'blue' },
        { id: 3, color: 'red' }
    ];      

    things = JSON.stringify( things);
    var name="test";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/PassThings',
        data: {
            things:things,
            name:name
       },
        success: function () {          
            $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

C#:
Here is my C# code.Controller.

```
public void PassThings(List<Thing> things,string name)
{
    var t = things;
    var namePass=name;
}
```

//Model

```
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

error name is undefined.and list is null.please help me.

Comment: You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` and specify contentType in request

Comment: As far as I know, serializing objects is case-sensitive. So, id should be Id and color Color in your things[] var.

Comment: @Bas,Nope you're wrong, its not case-sensitive.

Comment: @MuhammadAzim, Everything looks great, just remove that ` contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ajax `traditional: true` option and modify the way you stringify the data. Remove

```
things = JSON.stringify( things);
```

and adjust the ajax to

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: '@Url.Action("PassThings", "Home")', // recommended best practice
  traditional: true, // add this
  data: JSON.stringify({ things: things, name:name }), // modify this
  success: function () {
    ....
  }
});
```

Comment: Also need to remove  `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`.

Comment: @MokshShah, No you dont. Both properties would be `null` if you did that.

Comment: I've just tried this way, and it was an error saying `Invalid primitive type : things`

Comment: @MokshShah, The code in my answer is working - I just copied it from my project using OP's code and changing the lines I marked

Comment: How?... it looks weird , for me it says `Invalid JSON primitive : things`, how is it possible?, I can show you snapshot, tell me where should I post?

Comment: @MokshShah, Did you remove the `things = JSON.stringify( things);` line? Often that error is a result of omitting `JSON.stringify()` but doing it twice could be a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67526/discussion-between-moksh-shah-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score -1):

the list will be null. Resaon: JSON is a type of string, so when you are passing the json object `things` it will be a sting and not an List<> object.

In your c# code try this

```
public void PassThings(string things,string name)
{
   //deserialzie the "things" using newtonsoft json convert then bind to List<> model
}
```